# Introducing vulnerability for testing purposes

Tags: security, nessus

I am testing some scripts to compare our Tenable.io reports. I need to compare today's report with yesterday's report on the same Linux target.

I need to put some deliberate/test vulnerabilities to show the scripts actually work. Is there any short piece of code that Tenable.io can flag easily? Any piece of code or signature files that when put on the Linux target will show up in the Tenable.io scan report?

Comment: Possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file?

Comment: Have you tried asking Tenable support? They should be able to provide test artefacts to demonstrate their product is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks Nate and James for your suggesstions. Will work upon your suggesstions.